# Issue with a Spring @Async method not catching/rethrowing an exception

Tags: spring, asynchronous

I am facing an issue since I enabled turned a synchronous method into an asynchronous one: if an exception is thrown from within the body of the method, I can no longer rethrow it.

Let me first show the code:

My async/task executor configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAsync
public class AsyncConfiguration implements AsyncConfigurer {

    @Override
    public Executor getAsyncExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        taskExecutor.setCorePoolSize(5);
        taskExecutor.setMaxPoolSize(10);
        taskExecutor.setQueueCapacity(25);
        taskExecutor.initialize();
        return taskExecutor;
    }
}
```

My asynchronous method:

```
@Async
@Override
public void sendPasswordResetInfo(String email) {
    Assert.hasText(email);
    Member member = memberRepository.findByEmail(email);
    try {
        mailerService.doMailPasswordResetInfo(member);//EXCEPTION THROWN HERE
    } catch (MessagingException | MailSendException e) {
        log.error("MessagingException | MailSendException", e);
        // TODO: not thrown since @Async is used
        throw new MailerException("MessagingException | MailSendException");//NOT CALLED
    }
}
```

All I see in the console when an exception is raised by `mailerService.doMailPasswordResetInfo` is the following stacktrace:

```
2014-06-20 18:46:29,249 [ThreadPoolTaskExecutor-1] ERROR com.bignibou.service.preference.PreferenceServiceImpl - MessagingException | MailSendException
org.springframework.mail.MailSendException: Failed messages: javax.mail.SendFailedException: Invalid Addresses;
  nested exception is:
    com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPAddressFailedException: 550 5.1.1 Adresse d au moins un destinataire invalide. Invalid recipient. OFR204_418 [418]
; message exception details (1) are:
Failed message 1:
javax.mail.SendFailedException: Invalid Addresses;
  nested exception is:
    com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPAddressFailedException: 550 5.1.1 Adresse d au moins un destinataire invalide. Invalid recipient. OFR204_418 [418]

    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.rcptTo(SMTPTransport.java:1294)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:635)
    at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.doSend(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:424)
    at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.send(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:346)
    at org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl.send(JavaMailSenderImpl.java:341)
    at com.bignibou.service.mailer.MailerServiceImpl.doMailPasswordResetInfo(MailerServiceImpl.java:82)
    at com.bignibou.service.preference.PreferenceServiceImpl.sendPasswordResetInfo_aroundBody10(PreferenceServiceImpl.java:112)
    at com.bignibou.service.preference.PreferenceServiceImpl$AjcClosure11.run(PreferenceServiceImpl.java:1)
    at org.springframework.transaction.aspectj.AbstractTransactionAspect.ajc$around$org_springframework_transaction_aspectj_AbstractTransactionAspect$1$2a73e96cproceed(AbstractTransactionAspect.aj:59)
    at org.springframework.transaction.aspectj.AbstractTransactionAspect$AbstractTransactionAspect$1.proceedWithInvocation(AbstractTransactionAspect.aj:65)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:262)
    at org.springframework.transaction.aspectj.AbstractTransactionAspect.ajc$around$org_springframework_transaction_aspectj_AbstractTransactionAspect$1$2a73e96c(AbstractTransactionAspect.aj:63)
    at com.bignibou.service.preference.PreferenceServiceImpl.sendPasswordResetInfo_aroundBody12(PreferenceServiceImpl.java:108)
    at com.bignibou.service.preference.PreferenceServiceImpl$AjcClosure13.run(PreferenceServiceImpl.java:1)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.aspectj.AbstractAsyncExecutionAspect.ajc$around$org_springframework_scheduling_aspectj_AbstractAsyncExecutionAspect$1$6c004c3eproceed(AbstractAsyncExecutionAspect.aj:58)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.aspectj.AbstractAsyncExecutionAspect.ajc$around$org_springframework_scheduling_aspectj_AbstractAsyncExecutionAspect$1$6c004c3e(AbstractAsyncExecutionAspect.aj:62)
    at com.bignibou.service.preference.PreferenceServiceImpl.sendPasswordResetInfo(PreferenceServiceImpl.java:108)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.AsyncExecutionInterceptor$1.call(AsyncExecutionInterceptor.java:97)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPAddressFailedException: 550 5.1.1 Adresse d au moins un destinataire invalide. Invalid recipient. OFR204_418 [418]

    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.rcptTo(SMTPTransport.java:1145)
    ... 28 more
```

FYI, `MailerException` is a custom exception I used in the app. What really strikes me is that this `MailerException` exception does not appear to be caught nor rethrown...

Can anyone please help?

edit 1: I have modified my async service method as follows:

```
@Async
    @Override
    public Future<Void> sendPasswordResetInfo(String email) {
        Assert.hasText(email);
        Member member = memberRepository.findByEmail(email);
        try {
            mailerService.doMailPasswordResetInfo(member);
            return new AsyncResult<Void>(null);
        } catch (MessagingException | MailSendException e) {
            log.error("MessagingException | MailSendException", e);
            //HERE: HOW DO I SEND THE MailerException USING THE FUTURE??
            throw new MailerException("MessagingException | MailSendException");
        }
    }
```

However, I am **not sure how to send the MailerException to the web layer using the AsyncResult** from within the catch block above...

Comment: Check your imports... it is possible that you are using a different MessagingException.

Comment: Note that it doesn't make much sense to throw an exception and not return a `Future`. If you're running `@Async`, the exception will be caught by the `ExecutorService`, not by your code.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: very interesting. Can you please elaborate about returning a Future and exceptions..

Comment: See the relevant documentation [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html#scheduling-annotation-support-async).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your logs show

```
2014-06-20 18:46:29,249 [ThreadPoolTaskExecutor-1] ERROR com.bignibou.service.preference.PreferenceServiceImpl - MessagingException | MailSendException
```

which is logged by

```
log.error("MessagingException | MailSendException", e);
```

the `Exception` that is then thrown

```
throw new MailerException("MessagingException | MailSendException");//NOT CALLED
```

is caught by the `Thread` executed by the underlying `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor`. This code is run asynchronously so the exception is thrown in a different thread than the thread that invokes the method.

```
someCode();
yourProxy.sendPasswordResetInfo(someValue()); // exception thrown in other thread
moreCode();
```

If you make your method return a `Future` as shown [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html#scheduling-annotation-support-async) you'll be able to invoke `get()` on it and that will rethrow any exception that was thrown inside the `@Async` method, wrapped in an `ExecutionException`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I now understand better what is going on. The solution you suggest is somewhat difficult to implement in my case as it would imply changing the return type of my service method (in order to return a `Future`) and changing the controller method (calling method) in order to invoke `get()`. Do you think a [AsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/javadoc-api/org/springframework/aop/interceptor/AsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler.html) would help? (Spring 4.1)

Comment: @balteo Sure, depending on how you want to handle the exception. It seems that this `@Async` method is disconnected from the request after its been launched.

Comment: Oops. I forgot to mention I have an `@ExceptionHandler` in a `@ControllerAdvice` that is meant to handle the `MailerException` but that does not since I use @Async on the method.

Comment: By the way: do you have any idea how to configure and use a `AsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler` (`SimpleAsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler`)?

Comment: @balteo Spring MVC is a servlet based framework. Servlets (typically) work a on single threaded model. One thread handles the full request. So the same thread that invokes your controller's handler method would also invoke the `@ExceptionHandler` method. But you say you want the mailsender to run asynchronously but still have the `@ExceptionHandler` handle its exception. That doesn't make much sense. I hope you see what I mean.

Comment: @balteo That class is very new. I haven't tried the new Spring snapshot.

Comment: I understand what you mean about Servlets' single thread model. But how can the frontend somehow handle an exception thrown by an "asynchronous" thread? I need users to be notified that something went wrong... I am really stuck here and taking into account what you say,the AsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler is of no use to me...

Comment: @balteo Why does the send mail have to be async? The `Future` may be the only solution, so that the container thread blocks and waits for the async thread to finish. And then join its result.

Comment: Hi Sotirios! I guess I'll have to use a Future then. What is worrying me is that I have to modify all the controller methods that call async  service methods returning Futures. Haven't I?

Comment: Also, how am I supposed to type parameterize the Future in this case? Future of Void?

Comment: @balteo Yes. Additionally, if you want handle exceptions with your `@ExceptionHandler`, you have to catch the `ExecutionException` from `get` and extract yours from the exception thrown and rethrow it.

Comment: I see, I have one interrogation still and I have edited my post accordingly.

Comment: @balteo Once you get the `Future` returned by `sendPasswordResetInfo`, call its `get()` somewhere down the line. That will throw an `ExecutionException` if an exception was thrown by the async method. That `ExecutionExeption` will have a `cause` which will be the exception actually thrown. You can retrieve it and rethrow it.

Comment: @balteo check out this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44138199/spring-exceptionhandler-and-multi-threading/45060491#45060491
it explains how to configure the AsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler. This configuration is required especially when the return type of your async method is void.

Answer (score 4):

By following this link http://www.baeldung.com/spring-async, you should create:

1. CustomAsyncExceptionHandler that implements AsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler

   ```
   @Slf4j
   public class CustomAsyncExceptionHandler implements AsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler {
     @Override
     public void handleUncaughtException(Throwable throwable, Method method, Object... obj) {
       log.error("**********************************************");
       log.error("Exception message - " + throwable.getMessage());
       log.error("Method name - " + method.getName());
       for (Object param : obj) {
           log.error("Parameter value - " + param);
       }
       log.error("**********************************************");
     }
   }
   ```
2. SpringAsyncConfig that implements AsyncConfigurer

   ```
   @Configuration
   @EnableAsync
   public class SpringAsyncConfig implements AsyncConfigurer {

     @Override
     public Executor getAsyncExecutor() {
       return new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
     }

     @Override
     public AsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler getAsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler() {
       return new CustomAsyncExceptionHandler();
     }
   }
   ```

Comment: This is all good an well, but how to then get exception somewherh outside the @Async method? Because in my case, I'd like to do some other dataabse operations based on the result

Answer (score 0):

The solution i had was fixed by creating a configuration class that extends AsyncConfigurerSupport, since the above solutions did not work in my implementation. In this configuration class, i had to define SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor and an async exception handler. Inside the handler, i checked the throwable instance and based on its value, i implemented the needed behavior:

```
if ( throwable instanceOf CustomException) {
// TODO add code
} else {
// TODO
}
```

Reference: [Effective advice on spring async exception handler](https://dzone.com/articles/effective-advice-on-spring-async-exceptionhandler-1)