# Notify the calling method about the exception occured in thread

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-mvc, exception

I am writing an Spring-mvc application.

I am executing task using `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor`.

I have below sample code.

**MyClass.java**

```
public class MyClass {
    public void startProcess() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor = //Initializing 
        for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
            taskExecutor.execute(new MyRunnable());
            // I can call taskExecutor.submit(task); also, if required
        }
    }
}
```

**MyRunnable.java**

```
public class MyRunnable implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void onRun() {
        try {
            //Code which generates exception like below
            throw new Exception("Runtime Exception");
        } catch (Exception e1) {
            // log or throw the exception
        }
    }
}
```

I want to notify `startProcess()` about the exception occurred in MyRunnable's run method.

Can any one please guide me for this.

I found below links but it is not solving my problem.

- [Handling exceptions from Java ExecutorService tasks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2248131/handling-exceptions-from-java-executorservice-tasks)
- http://java.dzone.com/articles/spring-async-and-exception

Thanks.

**Edit:**

One more question. If I am using @Async for asynchronous call to my some other method and If I want to check for the exception occured in async method then what should I do? As async method also returns future object.

Answer for @Async question I got from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24337275/3898076)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `Runnable`, implement `Callable`. A `Callable` can throw an exception, and when you retrieve the result of the Callable using a `Future`, you will get the exception thrown as an `ExecutionException`:

```
public class MyCallable implements Callable<Void> {
    public Void call() throws Exception {
        try {
            //Code which generates exception like below
            throw new Exception("Runtime Exception");
        } catch (Exception e1) {
            // log or throw the exception
        }
        return null; // To satisfy the method signature
    }
}
```

In MyClass:

```
List<Future<Void>> futures = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    Future<Void> future = taskExecutor.submit(new MyCallable());
    futures.add(future);
}

// After all tasks have started, now wait for all of them to complete (they run in parallel)
// and check if there were any exceptions

for (Future<Void> future : futures) {
    try {
        future.get();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        // Access the exception thrown by the different thread.
        e.getCause().printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Do I need to check for isDone() condition?

Comment: No, the `get` method (without a timeout) will already wait until its done. Except if your main thread is interrupted, but in that case you will get an `InterruptedException`.

Comment: One more question. I don't know it is related to this or not. If I am using @Async for asynchronous call to my some other method and If I want to check for the exception occured in async method then what should I do? As async method also returns future object.

Comment: Got my answer for @Async question here (http://stackoverflow.com/a/24337275/3898076).

Answer (score 1):

You can add constructor with some listener to your Thread.

Like:

ExceptionListener:

```
  public class ExceptionListener{
    public void doSomething(long threadId,Exception e){
      //...e.g., notify startProcess()
    }
  }
```

MyRunnable:

```
  public class MyRunnable implements Runnable {
    private ExceptionListener listener;

    private MyRunnable(ExceptionListener exception) {
      this.listener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
      //...
      listener.doSomething(Thread.currentThread().getId(),new Exception("Runtime Exception"));
      //...
    }
  }
```

startProcess():

```
  public void startProcess() {
    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor = //Initializing 
    ExceptionListener listener= new ExceptionListener();
    for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
        taskExecutor.execute(new MyRunnable(listener();
        // I can call taskExecutor.submit(task); also, if required
    }
  }
```

Or, you can use **Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler**, like described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6548203/3502543).

**edited.**

Clarification:

> if exception occurs, I have to stop my further execution of other
>   processes. So I want to catch or get notified about the exception in
>   startProcess method. –  Naman Gala 1 hour ago

Answer:

> I suppose that your worker thread will have **while** cycle. So you can just **pass volatile
>   boolean** to each thread and set it up to true or
>   false in case of exception, cycle condition will be this boolean
>   variable. –  Maksym 58 mins ago

Comment: You mean after calling execute method I should inspect `listener` in `startProcess`?

Comment: In UncaughtExceptionHandler example, should I pass single object of Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler to every thread or should I create individual object for every thread?

Comment: Actually in most cases you should handle exceptions in the same thread.  What do you want to achive ?

Comment: Should I pass single object of Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler to every thread or should I create individual object for every thread? -- > You are setting it to the thread object before starting it, like t.setUncaughtExceptionHandler(Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler); So it's up to you have one for all or different for each...

Comment: if exception occurs, I have to stop my further execution of other processes. So I want to catch or get notified about the exception in startProcess method.

Comment: I suppose that your worker thread will have while cycle. So you can just pass volatile boolean to each thread and set it up to true or false in case of exception, cycle condition will be this boolean variable.

Comment: I think Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler is for handling uncaught exception. It will not notify about the exception. Correct me if I am wrong. Your approach can solve my problem.