# Spring @ExceptionHandler and multi-threading

Tags: java, spring, multithreading

I've got the following controller advice:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ExceptionHandlerAdvice {

    @ExceptionHandler(NotCachedException.class)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
    public ModelAndView handleNotCachedException(NotCachedException ex) {
        LOGGER.warn("NotCachedException: ", ex);
        return generateModelViewError(ex.getMessage());
    }

}
```

It works great most of the time but when the NotCachedException is thrown from a method annotated with @Async, the exception is not handled properly.

```
@RequestMapping(path = "", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
@Async
public ResponseEntity<String> store(@Valid @RequestBody FeedbackRequest request, String clientSource) {
    cachingService.storeFeedback(request, ClientSource.from(clientSource));
    return new ResponseEntity<>(OK);
}
```

Here is the config of the Executor:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAsync
public class Application {

private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Application.class);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
        SettingsConfig settings = context.getBean(SettingsConfig.class);
        LOGGER.info("{} ({}) started", settings.getArtifact(), settings.getVersion());
        createCachingIndex(cachingService);
    }

    @Bean(name = "matchingStoreExecutor")
    public Executor getAsyncExecutor() {
        int nbThreadPool = 5;
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        executor.setCorePoolSize(nbThreadPool);
        executor.setMaxPoolSize(nbThreadPool * 2);
        executor.setQueueCapacity(nbThreadPool * 10);
        executor.setThreadNamePrefix("matching-store-executor-");
        executor.initialize();
        return executor;
    }

}
```

What can I do in order to make it work with @Async annotated methods?

Comment: What do you mean with "the exception is not handled properly"?

Comment: @snovelli The ExceptionHandler methods in the ControllerAdvice just doesn't see the exceptions.

Comment: @Rlarroque Which version of Spring are you using ?

Comment: @gnostrenoff Spring Boot 1.4.5

Comment: @Rlarroque have you looked into http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#scheduling-annotation-support-exception ? Maybe this could help your exception handling

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The default exception handling machenism does not work in case of @Async Enabled.
To handle exception thrown from methods annotated with @Async, you need to implement a custom AsyncExceptionHandler as.

```
public class AsyncExceptionHandler implements AsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler{
    @Override
    public void handleUncaughtException(Throwable ex, Method method, Object... params) {
        // Here goes your exception handling logic.

    }
}
```

Now You need to configure this customExceptionHandler in you Application class as

```
@EnableAsync
public class Application implements AsyncConfigurer {
     @Override Executor getAsyncExecutor(){
      // your ThreadPoolTaskExecutor configuration goes here. 
}


@Override
public AsyncUncaughExceptionHandler getAsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler(){
   return new AsyncExceptionHandler();
}
```

Note: Make sure in order to make your AsyncExceptionHandler work you need to implement AsyncConfigurer in your Application class.

Comment: Would you need to implement AsyncConfigurer if you are using spring boot?

Comment: Why it is answer? AsyncUncaughExceptionHandler doesn't have a sink to send HTTP response. Just logging a stacktrace is not enough.

Answer (score 0):

[@Async](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-async) shouldn't be used on controller methods as you would have one thread per request anyway. More details: [is using @Async and CompletableFuture in controller can increase performance of our api?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65120202/is-using-async-and-completablefuture-in-controller-can-increase-performance-of)

If a service method like `cachingService.storeFeedback` takes long time to be completed and you want immediate response from endpoint then it could be annotated `@Async` in the service layer so `cachingService.storeFeedback` could be executed in the background.

For controller method below, neither `@ExceptionHandler` nor [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45060491/5962766) would help to return HTTP error response if exception would occur in the void `@Async` service method:

```
@RequestMapping(path = "", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
public ResponseEntity<String> store(@Valid @RequestBody FeedbackRequest request, String clientSource) {
    cachingService.storeFeedback(request, ClientSource.from(clientSource));
    return new ResponseEntity<>(OK);
}
```

If controller would return `Future` from `@Async` service then `@ExceptionHandler` should be sufficient to handle endpoint errors:

```
@RequestMapping(path = "", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
public CompletableFuture<String> store(@Valid @RequestBody FeedbackRequest request, String clientSource) {
    return cachingService.storeFeedback(request, ClientSource.from(clientSource));
}
```

According to [How To Do @Async in Spring](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-async):

> When a method return type is a Future, exception handling is easy.
> Future.get() method will throw the exception.
>
> But if the return type is void, exceptions will not be propagated to
> the calling thread. So, we need to add extra configurations to handle
> exceptions.