# How to change response statuc code when using CompletableFuture.exceptionaly() in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, asynchronous, spring-boot

I have a simple controller:

```
@RestController
public class SimpleController() {

    public String get() {
        if (System.nanoTime() % 2 == 0)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("oops");

        return "ok"
    }
}
```

Controller can throw simple exception, so i wrote controller advisor for it handling:

```
@ExceptionHandler(IllegalArgumentException.class)
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<String> rejection(Rejection ex) {
    return new ResponseEntity<>("bad", HttpStatus.CONFLICT);
}
```

Now i want to make get method async. But i don't know the best way for handling exception.

I tried:

```
    public CompletableFuture<String> get() {
        CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(
            () -> {
                if (System.nanoTime() % 2 == 0)
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("oops");

                return "ok";
            }).exceptionally(thr -> {
                //what should i do?
                if (thr instanceof IllegalArgumentException)
                    throw ((IllegalArgumentException) t);

                if (thr.getCause() instanceof IllegalArgumentException)
                    throw ((IllegalArgumentException) t.getCause());

                return null;
            }
    }
```

But controller advisor still does not catch the exception.

Also i tried to return ResponseEntity("message", HttpStatuc.CONFLICT); in exceptionally block.
But in tests i still have MvcResult.getResponse().getStatus() == 200.

Any other idea?
Maybe it's a wrong way at all?

**UPDATE**
I don't know why, but it don't catch exceptions:

```
    @Override
    public AsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler getAsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler() {
    return new AsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler() {
        @Override
        public void handleUncaughtException(Throwable ex, Method method, Object... params) {
            System.out.println();
        }
    };
```

And even if it work, how to set http status to response?

Comment: http://javasampleapproach.com/java/java-8/java-8-completablefuture-handle-exception

Comment: .handle() is almost the same with .exceptionally(), except it calls all time. So i still don't know  hot to change the HttpStatus of async response.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44138199/spring-exceptionhandler-and-multi-threading

Comment: Still not work for me. :(

Answer (score 0):

Try to return a `ResponseEntity` instance:

```
return new ResponseEntity<>("bad", HttpStatus.CONFLICT);
```

out of `exceptionally` method.

Comment: Where should i return it?

Comment: exceptionally(thr -> new ResponseEntity<>("bad", HttpStatus.CONFLICT));

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys, the problem not in code.
I just wrote bad tests.
Here the link for explaining:

https://sdqali.in/blog/2015/11/24/testing-async-responses-using-mockmvc/

Just use:

```
MvcResult result = mockMvc.perform(...).andReturn();
result = mockMvc.perform(asyncDispatch(result)).andReturn();
```

before you check the status or result response.