# is using @Async and CompletableFuture in controller can increase performance of our api?

Tags: java, spring, performance, asynchronous, completable-future

What I am trying to achieve is can I get a better performance by using @Async and CompletableFuture as result in my controller of my RESTApi by using the multi threading in this simple way?

here is what I do, here is my controller :

```
@PostMapping("/store")
@Async
public CompletableFuture<ResponseEntity<ResponseRequest<CategoryBpsjResponseDto>>> saveNewCategoryBPSJ(@Valid @RequestBody InputRequest<CategoryBPSJRequestDto> request) {
    
    CompletableFuture<ResponseEntity<ResponseRequest<CategoryBpsjResponseDto>>> future = new CompletableFuture<>();

    future.complete(ResponseEntity.ok(new ResponseRequest<>("Okay", categoryBPSJService.save(request))));
    return future;
}
```

**VS**

```
@PostMapping("/store")
public ResponseEntity<ResponseRequest<CategoryBpsjResponseDto>> saveNewCategoryBPSJ(@Valid @RequestBody InputRequest<CategoryBPSJRequestDto> request) {
    
    return ResponseEntity.ok(new ResponseRequest<>("okay", categoryBPSJService.save(request));
}
```

as you can see in my first controller function, I add the CompletableFuture on my function response, but in my service, which is I do save in this line `categoryBPSJService.save(request)` is not async, just a simple function that looked like this :

```
public CategoryBpsjResponseDto save(InputRequest<CategoryBPSJRequestDto> request) {
    CategoryBPSJRequestDto categoryBPSJDto = request.getObject();

    Boolean result = categoryBPSJRepository.existsCategoryBPSJBycategoryBPSJName(categoryBPSJDto.getCategoryBPSJName());

    if(result){
        throw new ResourceAlreadyExistException("Category BPSJ "+ categoryBPSJDto.getCategoryBPSJName() + " already exists!");
    }

    CategoryBPSJ categoryBPSJ = new CategoryBPSJ();
    categoryBPSJ = map.DTOEntity(categoryBPSJDto);

    categoryBPSJ.setId(0L);
    categoryBPSJ.setIsDeleted(false);

    CategoryBPSJ newCategoryBPSJ = categoryBPSJRepository.save(categoryBPSJ);
    
    CategoryBpsjResponseDto categoryBpsjResponseDto = map.entityToDto(newCategoryBPSJ);

    return categoryBpsjResponseDto;

}
```

I just return simple Object with JPA connection, with this is way will my request performance increased? or am I missing something to increase it? or it make no difference with or without CompletableFuture and @Async on my controller?

*note : my project is based on java 13

Comment: If you're trying to "increase performance" (which can mean any of several things), you first need to measure your application to determine where any performance problems are.

Comment: I don't think this is really useful. If you are in an application server, the AS has a thread pool to answer to web requests. What you do here is you release the web thread, but move it to the thread pool used by Spring. So for me there is no advantage. Using asynchronous may be useful when your service needs to wait for an external ressource. If you are using Spring boot, have a look at spring webflux.

Comment: Not really, you only free the request handling threads and theoretically allowing for more requests to be concurrently handled. It will not improve performance as processing takes the same amount of time. Also both `@Async` and `CompletableFuture` is wrong, use `CompletableFuture` don't use `@Async` on a controller method.

Comment: ohh, i only have advantage too free the request handling threads right? @M.Deinum but not increasing the speed of my controller response? what is the advantage of "free the request handling threads"? is that something i can consider it as a plus?

Comment: If you have a lot of concurrent users and a lot of short lived tasks and some long running. If tomcat is busy handling those long running tasks it cannot handle the short lived ones because there are no more threads to handle the request. Offloading those requests to another threadpool will quickly frree up those threads so that it can keep on processing the other requests.

Comment: if there is 100 user request coming to that controller with CompletableFuture, can that 100 request count as concurrent request? all in the same time, they clicking the save button to hit that API @M.Deinum

Comment: That is what concurrent means...But it is not only that controller, there are also other requests handled by Tomcat (assuming that that is your container) serving other pages/parts of your application.

Comment: Ohh thats mean, its better to have CompleteableFuture at our controller as the response, it will help when concurrent request start getting much request right?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Using CompletableFuture won't magically improve the performances of your server.

If you're using [Spring MVC](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web.html#mvc), built on the Servlet API usually on top of Jetty or Tomcat, you'll have one thread per request. The pool those threads are taken from is usually pretty big, so that you can have a decent amount of concurrent requests. Here, blocking a request thread isn't that of an issue, as this thread is handling that single request only anyway, meaning other requests won't be blocked (unless there's no thread available in the pool anymore). This means, your IOs *can* be blocking, your code *can* be synchronous.

If you're using [Spring WebFlux](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web-reactive.html#spring-web-reactive) though, usually on top of Netty, requests are handled as messages/events: one thread can handle multiple requests, which allows reducing the size of the pool (threads are expensive). In this case, blocking on a thread *is* an issue, as it can/will lead to other requests waiting for the IO to finish. This means, your IOs *must* be non-blocking, your code *must* be asynchronous, so that the thread can be released and handle another request "in the meantime" instead of just waiting idle for the operation to finish. Just FYI, this reactive stack looks appealing, but it comes with many other drawbacks to be aware of, because of the asynchronous nature of the codebase.

JPA is blocking, because it relies on JDBC (which blocks on the IOs). This means, using JPA with Spring WebFlux doesn't make much sense and should be avoided, as it goes against the principle of "do not block a request thread". People have found workarounds (e.g. running the SQL queries from within another thread pool), but this doesn't really solve the underlying issue: the IOs will block, contention can/will occur. People are working on asynchronous SQL drivers for Java (e.g. [Spring Data R2DBC](https://spring.io/projects/spring-data-r2dbc) and the underlying vendor-specific drivers), which can be used from within a WebFlux codebase for instance. Oracle started working on their own asynchronous driver too, ADBA, but [they abandoned the project](https://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/jdbc-spec-discuss/2019-September/000529.html) because of their focus on *fibers* via [Project Loom](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/%7Erpressler/loom/loom/sol1_part1.html) (which might soon totally change the way concurrency is handled in Java).

You seem to be using Spring MVC, meaning relying on the thread-per-request model. Just dropping CompletableFuture in your code won't improve things. Say you delegate all your service layer logic onto another thread pool than the default request thread pool: your request threads will be available, yes, but contention will now happen on that other thread pool of yours, meaning you'll just be moving your problem around.

Some cases might still be interesting to postpone to another pool, e.g. computationally intensive operations (like passphrase hashing), or certain actions that would trigger a lot of (blocking) IOs, etc., but be aware that contention can still happen, meaning requests can still be blocked/waiting.

If you *do* observe performance issues with your codebase, **profile it first**. Use tools like [YourKit](https://www.yourkit.com/) (many others available) or even APMs like [NewRelic](https://newrelic.com/products/application-monitoring) (many others available as well). Understand where the bottlenecks are, fix the worsts, repeat. That being said, some usual suspects:

- too many IOs (especially with JPA, e.g. [*select n+1*](https://vladmihalcea.com/n-plus-1-query-problem/)),
- too many serialisations/deserialisations (especially with JPA, e.g. [eager fetching](https://vladmihalcea.com/eager-fetching-is-a-code-smell/)).

Basically, JPA is *the* usual suspect: it's a powerful tool, but very easy to misconfigure, you need to *think SQL* to get it right IMHO. I highly recommend [logging the generated SQL queries](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2536829/1225328) when developing, you might be surprised. [Vlad Mihalcea's blog](https://vladmihalcea.com/tag/jpa/) is a good resource for JPA related things. Interesting read as well: [OrmHate by Martin Fowler](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/OrmHate.html).

---

Concerning your specific code snippet, say you're going vanilla Java without Spring's `@Async` support:

```java
CompletableFuture<ResponseEntity<ResponseRequest<CategoryBpsjResponseDto>>> future = new CompletableFuture<>();
future.complete(ResponseEntity.ok(new ResponseRequest<>("Okay", categoryBPSJService.save(request))));
return future;
```

This won't make `categoryBPSJService.save(request)` run asynchronously. It will be made more obvious if you split your code a bit:

```
CategoryBpsjResponseDto categoryBPSJ = categoryBPSJService.save(request)
CompletableFuture<ResponseEntity<ResponseRequest<CategoryBpsjResponseDto>>> future = new CompletableFuture<>();
future.complete(ResponseEntity.ok(new ResponseRequest<>("Okay", categoryBPSJ)));
return future;
```

See what happened here? `categoryBPSJ` will be called synchronously, and you'll then create an already-completed future holding the result. If you really wanted to use a CompletableFuture here, you'd have to use a supplier:

```
CompletableFuture<CategoryBpsjResponseDto> future = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(
    () -> categoryBPSJService.save(request),
    someExecutor
);
return future.thenApply(categoryBPSJ -> ResponseEntity.ok(new ResponseRequest<>("Okay", categoryBPSJ)));
```

[Spring's `@Async`](https://spring.io/guides/gs/async-method/) is basically just syntax sugar for the above, use either/or. For technical AOP/proxying reasons, a method annotated with `@Async` does need to return a CompletableFuture indeed, in which case returning an already-completed future is fine: Spring will make it run in an executor anyway. The service layer is usually the one being "async" though, the controller just consumes and composes over the returned future:

```
CompletableFuture<CategoryBpsjResponseDto> = categoryBPSJService.save(request);
return future.thenApply(categoryBPSJ -> ResponseEntity.ok(new ResponseRequest<>("Okay", categoryBPSJ)));
```

Make sure it all behaves as you expect by debugging your code, IDEs show which thread is currently being blocked by a breakpoint.

---

Side note: that's a simplified summary of what I understood from blocking vs non-blocking, MVC vs WebFlux, sync vs async, etc. It's quite superficial, some of my points might not be specific enough to be 100% true.

Comment: Woah, this is the explanation that i seek. You selved my curiosity, thanks sp00m

Comment: "The pool those threads are taken from is usually pretty big" - its only 200. Thats not so big?