# What are impact to my spring boot application if I have task executor

Tags: java, spring-boot, threadpoolexecutor

I already have the configuration to config for min and max threads for my spring boot application

```
server.tomcat.threads.min=20
server.tomcat.threads.max=50
```

What are impact to my spring boot application if I have task executor in my application?

```
@Configuration
public class AsyncConfiguration {

@Bean("myExecutor")
public TaskExecutor getAsyncExecutor() {
    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    executor.setCorePoolSize(20);
    executor.setMaxPoolSize(1000);
    executor.setWaitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown(true);
    executor.setThreadNamePrefix("Async-");
    return executor;
} }
```

Comment: You should post this as an answer, since it definitely is one, not just a comment.

Comment: in case one request coming, I want to log the error in the background. So I need to create one more thread, correct? If I have 2000 requests. Using task executor will be create 1000 threads, and without task executor will create 2000 threads, does my understanding is correct?

Comment: Yes, if you use the task executor in this fashion. But you didn't specify this in your question. You should clarify what exactly you want to achieve to get proper answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are two different thread pools:

- `server.tomcat.threads.*` defines the request thread pool (knowing that the Servlet API uses one thread per request)
- `myExecutor` is just another pool that you could use for async operations, for instance via [`@EnableAsync`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/EnableAsync.html)/`@Async`:

> By default, Spring will be searching for an associated thread pool definition: either a unique [`TaskExecutor`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/task/TaskExecutor.html) bean in the context, or an [`Executor`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html?is-external=true) bean named "taskExecutor" otherwise. If neither of the two is resolvable, a [`SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/task/SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor.html) will be used to process async method invocations.

See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/65185737/1225328 for more details about using thread pools with Spring MVC/WebFlux.

So, to answer your actual question: both configurations don't interfere with each other :)

Comment: Thank your your answer. Can you help to share max and min thread by default from Spring for SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor?

Comment: According to its [javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/task/SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor.html), _by default, the number of concurrent threads is unlimited_.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding

```
server.tomcat.threads.* : it tomcat thread pool which using for requests.
```

It mean If I have 2000 request coming, it only create 50 threads as my configuration.

```
myExcutor: it is using for Asynchronous.
```

In case I want to handle for logging error in the background by using @Async annotation, If all 2000 request got fail, it create max 1000 threads. So tomcat will manage 50 threads as main threads and Spring Container will manage 1000 threads. But If I not use a custom task executor, it will use default from Spring and create 2000 new threads. In that case, my application will be slower